# how to disable cache for cms block?

Tags: catalog, category, cache

unfortunately in this situation I do not have $this->getChildHtml to assign false to it and then change my xml file for disabling cache I have this block in view.phtml:

```
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

and the function is in view.php as follow:

```
public function getCmsBlockHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
            ->setBlockId($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage())
            ->toHtml();
        $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
    }
    return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
}
```

any ideas on how to disable the cache here? my page is in category folder when displaying the products

**Update**:with help of Denis I understood that (for some pages) when I have something in constructor if the cache is enabled the constructor will not be called! and so I think that's the reason why setting the cache life time doesn't work there

Answer (score 2):

To disable Block Html Cache you should set cacheLifeTime to null. You can see more details in Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::_loadCache()

```
protected function _loadCache()
{
    if (is_null($this->getCacheLifetime()) || !$this->_getApp()->useCache(self::CACHE_GROUP)) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mage_*_Block_Template classes you can control the cache through the constructor

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
                    'cache_lifetime'   => 86400, //1 day
                    'cache_tags'   => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG), //for adding in product detail page
                    'cache_key'   => 'some-identifier' //optional, but should be unique if used
    ));
}
```

In definition createBlock function, we have three parameters:

```
public function createBlock ($type, $name = '', $attributes = array())
```

You can then use the parameters to pass attributes of the data cache, like this:

```
$html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block','',
    array(
        'cache_lifetime' => false,
        'cache_tags' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG)
    ))
    ->setBlockId($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage())
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: I added the constructor in view.php and then I added the block attributes just like you said but unfortunately I am not seeing any difference

Comment: Try use 1 in 'cache_lifetime' value (1 ms for lifetime). I'll test it soon.

Comment: as I updated the question the problem is that the constructor only performs when cache is disabled

Comment: It's not work for me