# How I can disable cache for one file that include in cms page?

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, cms-pages

I have including of phtml file in cms page (home page) 
`{{block type="catalog/product_new" product_ids="6747,4652,605,571,518,182,4432,4425" template="catalog/product/home_slider.phtml" }}`, and I need no-caching this phtml file. How to disable cache for this?

```
{block type="catalog/product_new" product_ids="6747,4652,605,571,518,182,4432,4425" template="catalog/product/home_slider.phtml" cache_lifetime="null"}}  - not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add cache_lifetime="null" to every inclusion of this block.

for example if you add block in CMS content:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id" cache_lifetime="null"}}
```

or if you add block in XML:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
     <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>null</lifetime></action>
</block>
```

Comment: I include this block in my cms/page, I'm sorry, but I saw that is no cms statick block ---- {{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/home_slider.phtml"}} and when I'm add cache_lifetime="null" in declaration {{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/home_slider.phtml" cache_lifetime="null"}} , my block is not working

Answer (score 2):

What Magento are u using?
1, 2?
CE, EE?
Any modules for caching?

EDIT:

I see.
It should work:
[how to disable cache for a CMS page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53999/how-to-disable-cache-for-a-cms-page)
[how to disable cache for cms block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31927/how-to-disable-cache-for-cms-block)

Comment: Magento Version 1.8.1.0,  CE, without any modules for caching